# Running db2 from bash script not working?

Tags: sql, bash, db2

I'm currently using bash on CentOS. DB2 is installed and `db2` is on my path.

I have a few lines in a script which are supposed to update my db2 database, but they aren't working. As a minimal reproduction, I can do the exact same thing right in the bash command line and get the same error. Here's that reproduction:

```
$ db2 connect to PLT02345 user uni using uni; db2 update USM_USER set STATUS = 1 where NAME = 'asm_admin'
```

I expect this to set `STATUS` to `1` for everything in `PLT02345.USM_USER` where the `NAME` is currently `asm_admin`.

Instead, I get an error about `"ASM_ADMIN"` not being valid in the context where it's used. Here's the full output:

```
  Database Connection Information

Database server        = DB2/LINUXX8664 10.1.2
SQL authorization ID   = UNI
Local database alias   = PLT02345

DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0206N  "ASM_ADMIN" is not valid in the context where it is used.
SQLSTATE=42703
```

I'm confused - what about this makes it not valid? Is bash somehow mutilating the command and not passing everything as it should to db2?

Answer (score 2):

If you're running this from the command line, Bash will drop the `'`s off `'asm_admin'` because it simply assumes you're passing a string.  The end result is the SQL becoming `WHERE name = asm_admin` which is invalid.

To correct this, you need to quote your whole command:

```
db2 "update USM_USER set STATUS = 1 where NAME = 'asm_admin'"
```

Comment: Full disclosure: I'm unfamiliar with db2 itself, but does the `connect` persist across multiple `db2` calls?  That may also require fixing.

Comment: @mr-llama Yes, the DB2 command line processor is built so that a connection does persist across calls.